# Uncaught ReferenceError: dbb is not defined at file:///android_asset/www/index.html (Phonegap)

Tags: cordova

I have a basic piece of code made with Phonegap that insert values in a sql lite table. But when i try to push the button for this action, the log shows the messasge: "Uncaught ReferenceError: dbb is not defined at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:116". All the code inside an html file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=default-width; user-scalable=no" />
   <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">

   <title>Embedded Sql Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>

<!-- main scripts used in this example -->
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

var db;
var shortName = 'WebSqlDB';
var version = '1.0';
var displayName = 'WebSqlDB';
var maxSize = 65535;

function errorHandler(transaction, error) {
   alert('Error: ' + error.message + ' code: ' + error.code);

}

function successCallBack() {
   alert("DEBUGGING: success");

}

function nullHandler(){};


function onBodyLoad(){

alert("DEBUGGING: we are in the onBodyLoad() function");

 if (!window.openDatabase) {

   alert('Databases are not supported in this browser.');
   return;
 }

 db = openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName,maxSize);

 db.transaction(function(tx){

  // you can uncomment this next line if you want the User table to be empty each time the application runs
  // tx.executeSql( 'DROP TABLE User',nullHandler,nullHandler);

   tx.executeSql( 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS User(UserId INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, FirstName TEXT NOT NULL, LastName TEXT NOT NULL)', [],nullHandler,errorHandler);
 },errorHandler,successCallBack);

}

function ListDBValues() {

 if (!window.openDatabase) {
  alert('Databases are not supported in this browser.');
  return;
 }

 $('#lbUsers').html('');

 db.transaction(function(transaction) {
   transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM User;', [],
     function(transaction, result) {
      if (result != null && result.rows != null) {
        for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
          var row = result.rows.item(i);
          $('#lbUsers').append('<br>' + row.UserId + '. ' +
row.FirstName+ ' ' + row.LastName);
        }
      }
     },errorHandler);
 },errorHandler,nullHandler);

 return;

}

function AddValueToDB() {

 if (!window.openDatabase) {
   alert('Databases are not supported in this browser.');
   return;
 }

 db.transaction(function(transaction) {
   transaction.executeSql('INSERT INTO User(FirstName, LastName) VALUES (?,?)',[$('#txFirstName').val(), $('#txLastName').val()], nullHandler,errorHandler);
   });

 ListDBValues();

 return false;

}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="onBodyLoad();">
<h1>WebSQL</h1>
<input id="txFirstName" type="text" placeholder="FirstName">
<input id="txLastName" type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
<input type="button" value="Add record" onClick="AddValueToDB();">
<input type="button" value="Refresh" onClick="ListDBValues();"> <br>
<br>
<span style="font-weight:bold;">Currently stored values:</span>
<span id="lbUsers"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where do you use "dbb". It's not in the HTML you posted. Can you do a search for "dbb" or "dbb." in your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like you call openDatabase just fine. However if you take a look at the sample from Cordova ( http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#openDatabase ) you'll notice that the example is listening for the deviceready event rather than waiting for the body to load. When the deviceready event fires, it means that the Cordova API is ready to use. When the body loads that just means the WebClient has finished loading the page but doesn't guarantee that everything else is ready.